# Animate css slideInDown

Tags: css, animation, transform, animate.css, mobile-webkit

I am using animate.cs from

https://animate.style/

And trying to create some sliding animation with class **slideInUp** and **slideInDown**, when i Want to use some slideInUp element goes nice from bottom to up. The problem I have is when i want **slideInDown** it loooks like entire element just goes up overflow and entire element on animation is visibile and scrolling to bottom with entire content. All I need is that he just slide in down and not from top of page, just from position that he is

Here is properties fro **slideInDown**

```
  @-webkit-keyframes slideInDown {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      visibility: visible;
    }

    to {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideInDown {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      visibility: visible;
    }

    to {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  .animate__slideInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideInDown;
    animation-name: slideInDown;
  }
```

I need just element to scroll down from current position not from top of page, thanks

Here is working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1fbwrqgp/1/

You will see that slide div slide down from top of page i want to slide from parent and not from top

Comment: Please create a snippet with toold `<>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1fbwrqgp/1/

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.0/animate.css"); /* Using a url */

.scroll-div{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='animate__animated animate__slideInDown scroll-div'>

</div>
```

**What is changed?** I put `top: 200px` on `.scroll-div` to make it appears after the window top, also I modified `height: 200px` to `height: 100px` to make for you the animation more evident

Comment: The problem I have i dont have wrapper:(

Comment: This is just for showing, on scroll-div i am toggling the class :(

Comment: I just edited the JSFiddle you provided... so the HTML structure has only `<div class='animate__animated animate__slideInDown scroll-div'></div>`?

Comment: Yes, just one div

Comment: I adapted the code now removing the `.wrapper` div, let me know if this is what you are looking for